# Bitbucket SSH authentication

Tags: ssh

I have a problem connecting with my SSH service,

ssh-agent is running:

> ps -e | grep ssh
>   12163 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent

and caches my only identity:

> ssh-add -l
>   4096 25:56:f4:9c:09:65:fe:39:b3:17:73:bd:3c:76:3f:8d /home/matthias/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

everything exists as it should:

> ls ~/.ssh/
>   id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts

and id_rsa.pub is uploaded to Bitbucket.org SSH-Keys section..

However SSH authentication fails (using the verbose mode, one can see, that it somehow tries to load the non-existing id_dsa file)

> ssh -v -T hg@bitbucket.org
>   [...]
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:matthias_hueser
>   debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
>   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
>   debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
>   debug1: read PEM private key done: type 
>   Enter passphrase for key '/home/matthias/.ssh/id_rsa':
>  
>   debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
>   debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:matthias_hueser
>   debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_dsa
>   no such identity: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
>   debug1: Trying private key: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   no such identity: /home/matthias/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
>   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

Has somebody else run into the same problem and has
a suggestion?

[Thanks for the Edit]

Comment: Are the permissions 700 for `~/.ssh` and 600 for your keys? From the debug log it doesn’t look like this is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The output you're seeing looks consistent with the server rejecting your `id_rsa` key. ssh will check for `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, and `id_ecdsa` even if you don't specify them on the command-line or have them loaded in your ssh-agent.

If I were troubleshooting this, I'd remove ssh-agent from the picture and specify your private key on the command-line.

Run this in a new shell you'll close afterward, so you don't trash your existing environment:

```
$ bash
$ unset SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK
$ ssh -v -T -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa hg@bitbucket.org
[...]
$ exit
```

(ssh-keygen should prompt you for your key's password)

---

If that works, I'd double-check that the key your ssh-agent is providing is actually the correct one. You can

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And check that against what's in your ssh-agent:

```
$ ssh-add -L
```

If the identity in your agent is different, you should dump your keys with `ssh-add -D` and re-load them. If it's not different, I'm not sure what's up. Hope that helps a bit.